# Circuitikz common

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm learning Circuitikz to draw schematics in my reports.  I'd like to use the symbol for common; however, it doesn't seem to be there.  What are my options?

[image: Common symbol]

Thanks.

Example of use:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

Test TikZ image:
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=2] \draw
(0,0)   to[V, l=\SI{10}{\milli\volt}, -*]                   (0,2)
        to[R, l=\SI{1}{\kilo\ohm}, i=$i_{in}$, -*, n=r1]        (2,2)
        to[C, l=\SI{10}{\micro\farad}]                      (2,0)
(2,2)   to[R, l=\SI{10}{\kilo\ohm}, v_=$U(x)$]              (4,2)
        to[Tnpn, n=npn]                                     (4,0)
(2,3)   node[op amp] (opamp) {}
(opamp.+) -|                                                (0,2)

(0,0)   node[ground] {}
(2,0)   node[ground] {}
(4,0)   node[ground] {}
(r1) node[below=2mm] {A resistor!}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Some circuit.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Changing `ground` to `sground` causes a compilation error.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the `sground` symbol (p. 7 in the [circuitikz v 0.3.0 manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/circuitikz))?

Comment: Yep!  That manual is great!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Problem is, it errors when I do that saying it doesn't know what `sground` is.  I tried some of the other too, it doesn't know any of them but ground.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you're using an outdated version of `circuitikz`? Could you edit your question to include a small example document (starting from `\documentclass`) to show how you're trying to use the symbol?

Comment: Thanks for the example. It works fine for me with `sground`. Could you check in your `.log` file what version of `circuitikz` you're using?

Comment: Hmm!  That's no good! `Package: circuitikz 2009/11/18 The CircuiTikz circuit drawing package version 0
.2.4`

Comment: Okay, so you'll need to update the package, the signal ground (`sground`) was only [added in version 0.3.0](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/CHANGELOG)

Comment: Yep!  Thanks!  I'm doing that now.  Installing the latest version of texlive.  It's annoying the default one is old (in Ubuntu).